# Python Pandas - Create list of values AND count by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

What I would like to do is create a new column that contains a  unique list of all the dest_hostnames by the user_agent and user columns.

I also want another column that has the total count of events based on the useragent and user columns.

So the final dataset should look like:

[image]

I've been doing the following but can't figure out a way to do both so it's one in dataframe:

```
browsers.groupby(['user','user_agent'])['dest_hostname'].apply(list).reset_index(name='browser_hosts')

browsers.value_counts(["user", "user_agent"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use agg

```
df.groupby(['user', 'user_agent'])['dest_hostname'].agg(['unique', 'count'])
```

Comment: @HenryEcker, thanks, I missed the "contains a unique list" part of the question.